# How can a Mixer Hamiltonian restrict the search within a subspace of the statespace in QAOA?

Tags: optimization, qaoa

I understand that the role of the Mixer Hamiltonian prevents the creation of a constant function where there is nothing to be minimized.
I would like to understand from a mathematical perspective how the Mixer Hamiltonian controls the evolution in the statespace to include other states, as well as how with a particular choice of Mixer Hamiltonian, the search in the statespace is restricted to a chosen subspace.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09314 ? Besides the original paper introducing alternative QAOA mixers, it has a fairly clear explanation

Comment: Thanks I did and it makes sense now!